# Most efficient way to traverse Gmail attachments and download to Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Google Apps Script, is there a more efficient way to traverse my Gmail - picking out 'non-starred' emails that have a particular label assigned to them and then download the attachments to Google Drive?

My code works, but typically 'times out' after processing about 25 image attachments (using non-paid Gmail account)

The piece of code that does the work is as follows:

```
    // Loop through the messages for each thread
    for (var i = 0 ; i < messages.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
        var CurrentMsg = messages[i][j];
        
          if (!CurrentMsg.isStarred()){
            var att  = CurrentMsg.getAttachments();
            // If there were no attachments, create a 'dummy text file' to notify the user that there were no attachments for that email.
            var MsgSubject = CurrentMsg.getSubject();
            if (att.length == 0){
              var file = folder.createFile(MsgSubject,'There were no attachments',MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
            }
            else{  
              for (var k = 0; k < att.length; k++){
                var file = folder.createFile(att[k].copyBlob().getAs('image/jpeg').setName(MsgSubject));
              }
             }
            CurrentMsg.star();
          }
      }
    }
```

Any tips gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look through certain emails only, like those that are not starred in your case, consider using the [`search()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery). This will help you avoid looping over threads and messages you don't need.

If you need to bypass your maximum execution time, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738898/workaround-to-6-minutes-app-script-limits-on-google-drive-file-copying/68806969#68806969) and [this article](https://medium.com/geekculture/bypassing-the-maximum-script-runtime-in-google-apps-script-e510aa9ae6da) (also linked in the answer).

Comment: Hi Dmitry - thank you very much for taking the time to respond. I've never tried posting here so this is all a bit new to me and I should have provided a more specific question. I was aware of some of those articles to work around the timeout, but I was more interested to know if the method of creating a file for the attachment (using createFile method) was the most efficient way or if there was a better way to get the attachment 'saved' to google drive

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend limiting results via a `query` then using the `foreach` function to go through messages:

```
// limit the list of messages to iterate through
var query = 'has:attachment label:particular'; 

var results = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId, {q: query});
results.messages.forEach(function (m) {
    var msg = GmailApp.getMessageById(m.id);
    msg.getAttachments().forEach(function (a) {
        var fileName = a.getName();
        fileName = saveAttachmentToFolder(folder, a, fileName, msg.getDate(), input.tz);
    });
});
```

The code snippet above is based on a Gmail add-on that I created, specifically for saving attachments to labeled folders in Drive: https://github.com/ellaqezi/archiveByLabel/blob/main/Code.gs#L24

In the `label` field, you can define nested directories to create in Drive e.g. foo/bar.

In the `query` field, you can copy the parameters as you would use them in Gmail's search bar.